# user_posts facebook permission to access post privacy

Tags: facebook

I noticed that facebook allows users to change the privacy of all pass posts to "friends" but no option to change them to private or set them to a list. Using the user_posts permission, can I achieve this? Does this permission give access to the privacy of the post? Thank you in advance

Comment: `user_posts` does give you read access only. If you want to _set_ the privacy for existing posts – that would only be possible for posts that were created via your app in the first place.

Comment: As stated by @CBroe, the posts will need to have been created by your app. If that is the case then make a post request to `/post-id` with `privacy` set to `{'value':'SELF'}` to make it private. Allowed values are `enum{'EVERYONE', 'ALL_FRIENDS', 'FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS', 'CUSTOM', 'SELF'}`. Docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#privacy-param